# how should my query be so I can get my records?

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a table where I log when a car enters a parking lot, and I need to get the record close to a half hour.
For example I got

```
id, time date
1, 10:01 2016-05-30
2, 10:15 2016-05-30
3, 10,29 2016-05-30
4, 10:31 2016-05-30
5, 10:45 2016-05-30
6, 11:00 2016-05-30
7, 11:11 2016-05-30
8, 11:15 2016-05-30
```

So in my case I will get records: 3,6 and 8

For now I´m using something like:

```
.....
SELECT id, MAX(fecha) AS fecha, DATE_FORMAT(MAX(m.fecha), '%H:%i:%s') AS hora
FROM estacionamientos 
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '15:30:00' AND '16:00:00')
AND (DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2016-05-30')
UNION
SELECT id, MAX(fecha) AS fecha, DATE_FORMAT(MAX(m.fecha), '%H:%i:%s') AS hora
FROM estacionamientos 
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '16:00:01' AND '16:30:00')
AND (DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2016-05-30')
.....
ORDER BY hora DESC
```

But is there a better way than creating 48 unions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a way to do it, by grouping it with unix_timestamp:

```
SELECT id, fecha, DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%H:%i:%s') AS hora
FROM estacionamientos 
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '23:59:59')
AND (DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2016-05-30')
GROUP BY 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(fecha) DIV 1800
ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

Hope this helps anyone in the future.

Comment: Isn't (DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '23:59:59') redundant?